# How to rectify the error on page 109 of Kuldeep Singh's Linear Algebra: Step by Step (2013)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asking about a descriptive error on page 109 in [Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step* (2013)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199654441), marked in red below, during the proof process.

[image]

> The reduced row echelon form of matrix A cannot have a row (equation) of zeros, otherwise we would have n unknowns but less than n non-zero rows (equations), which means ~"

I think these sentences should be corrected as follows. Am I right?

> otherwise we would have r non-zero rows but less than n unknowns (equations)

Comment: The text says this anyway. After what you have cited, it it said $r<n$, so that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you. I recognized that part, but I asked you a question due to the increased confusion over the problematic part. Thanks to you, I found out that the sentence that follows the mentioned part was the correct sentence. Thank you again.